# Repositioning Toast in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, toast

I am trying to show a Toast at the top of the screen, but setting the gravity does not seem to be working:

```
fun showToastTop(context: Context, text: String, length: Int) {
    val toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, length)
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0)
    toast.show()
}
```

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            showToastTop(this, "My toast text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        }
    }
}
```

No matter where I call this function, the toast remains in its default position at the bottom of the screen. Is this way of repositioning Toasts incompatible with Compose or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As of Android 11, you can't really modify `Toast`s anymore: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#text-toast-api-changes. If you're testing on that version or above, that would be why.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Also, this isn't really a Jetpack Compose thing.  Using a Toast like that in the middle of a @Composable function is liable to cause...unexpected results.

Comment: I don't see how but okay :)